# a-frame 1.5.0 envMap with no-lights

Tags: aframe

I updated a-frame version to 1.5.0 but I have an issue with env maps.

[https://glitch.com/~better-incongruous-trollius](https://glitch.com/%7Ebetter-incongruous-trollius)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <a-scene id="myscene" light="defaultLightsEnabled: false">
      <a-assets>
        <a-cubemap id="worldenvmap">
          <img crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/93cb2d31-d256-4fcb-8b8e-db12192ccc88/envYup00.jpg?v=1711444964960">
          <img crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/93cb2d31-d256-4fcb-8b8e-db12192ccc88/envYup01.jpg?v=1711444965270">
          <img crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/93cb2d31-d256-4fcb-8b8e-db12192ccc88/envYup02.jpg?v=1711444965584">
          <img crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/93cb2d31-d256-4fcb-8b8e-db12192ccc88/envYup03.jpg?v=1711444966011">
          <img crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/93cb2d31-d256-4fcb-8b8e-db12192ccc88/envYup04.jpg?v=1711444966332">
          <img crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/93cb2d31-d256-4fcb-8b8e-db12192ccc88/envYup05.jpg?v=1711444966628">
        </a-cubemap>
        
        <a-asset-item id="sphere" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/93cb2d31-d256-4fcb-8b8e-db12192ccc88/model.obj?v=1711447695860"></a-asset-item>
        <a-asset-item id="balls" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/93cb2d31-d256-4fcb-8b8e-db12192ccc88/MetalRoughSpheres-(1)%20(1).glb?v=1711444768035"></a-asset-item>
      </a-assets>
      
       <a-obj-model id="spherem" src="#sphere" position="16 -4 -30" scale=".1 .1 .1"></a-obj-model>
      
         <a-entity 
          id="ballstest"
          gltf-model="#balls"
          position="0 1 -8" material="envMap:#worldenvmap">
      </a-entity>
      <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>

    
  </body>
  
  <script>
    
    setenvmap('ballstest');
    setenvmap('spherem');
    function setenvmap(assetId) {
      console.log('### -> ',assetId);
// setTimeOut represents app stage or user interaction
      setTimeout(()=>{
      let envMapS = document.querySelector('#worldenvmap');

      if (envMapS) {

        const paths = [];
        envMapS.childNodes.forEach(c => { if (c.src) { paths.push(c.src); } });
        if (paths.length === 6) {
          const loader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
          loader.setCrossOrigin('anonymous');
          // loader.setCrossOrigin('Access-Control-Allow-Origin');
          loader.setPath('');
          loader.format = THREE.RGBAFormat; // e.g. THREE.RGBFormat
          this.cubeTex = loader;
          this.texture = loader.load(paths);
        } else {
          console.error(`Invalid environment map on element '${el}'`)
        }

      }


      let thisel = document.getElementById(assetId);
      const mesh = thisel.getObject3D('mesh');
      const envMap = this.texture;
      envMap.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;   
      if (mesh) {

        mesh.traverse(function(node) {
          if (node.material && 'envMap' in node.material) {

            node.material.envMap = envMap;
            node.material.needsUpdate = true;
          }

        });
      }

    }, 4444)
  }


  </script>

</html>
```

in codes, scene has no lights also `defaultLightsEnabled: false`

All objects are black(no light) before applying envMap.
After applying envMap to objects, they are acting like there are lights in the scene.
This doesn't happen with A-frame 1.3.0, 1.4.0 and 1.4.2

Am I missing something with a-frame 1.5.0?